# Visual Studio c# should NOT start IIS website when debugging unit tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, iis, visual-studio-2013

I have a VS (2013) solution containing two unittest project's and a seperate webproject. The webproject has no relation to the unittest projects. The unittest projects is covering integration test of another solution and the webproject is a dashboard showing the results of these tests. They dont require each other to run as the test results are stored on an external server.

My issue is:
When I debug one of my tests (right click + debug test), the webproject is also started and the IIS express will be running. While this does not affect my tests, it is very annoying. How do I make sure the webproject is not automatically started when debugging the tests? The project is NOT set as startup project.

I know that I could simply create two separate solutions, but I want to keep the projects in a single solution.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7):

Click on your webproject, hit F4, there is an option "Always start when debugging", you should turn-off this option.

Comment: Perfect. Just the solution I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been looking all day for this issue! 
@stackman82, can you accept this answer as the solution?